# How to get the ID of last updated row in a single UPDATE statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Suppose I have a table `MyTable` where the primary key is `ID` and a composite unique key is `ColA` and `ColB`.

I want to retrieve the `ID` affected by an UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ColC='Blah'
WHERE ColA='xxx' and ColB='yyy'
```

Is there any way to do this using `sqlite3` in `python3` in a single statement without doing another SELECT after a successful UPDATE? I'm aware of `lastrowid` attribute on a cursor, but it seems to only apply to INSERTs.

More generally, I'm curious if any SQL engine allows for such functionality.

Comment: i doubt it because only in this contrived example is it guaranteed to be only one record updated ... it would need to handle all cases of update ... that said i really dont know and very well could be wrong

Comment: @JoranBeasley, just curious, when you said "only in this contrived example is it guaranteed to be only one record updated", are you saying that most real-world applications most likely will have stored procedures that alter other tables or rows upon an update statement?

Comment: consider `update blah set x=2 where 1=1`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, isn't that more contrived than my example?

Comment: ok consider a price increase then `update prices set price=price*1.1 where category=56`  this is a very common senario with updates... yes my previous example was indeed contrived to demonstrate an issue ... that said perhaps the other answer will help

Comment: What problem is solved by using a single statement?

Comment: @CL. let me refine the problem: update a single record and get the primary key/ID (assuming not composite) of that record in a single roundtrip between client program and SQLite (or other SQL engines).

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database; there is no such thing as a roundtrip. You need to actually measure the time needed for two statements before you can say it's too large.

Answer (score 2):

You asked if it could be done in some other DBMS, so I found this method in MySQL:

```
UPDATE MyTable as m1
JOIN (SELECT @id := id AS id
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE ColA = 'xxx' AND ColB = 'yyy') AS m2
ON m1.id = m2.id
SET m1.ColC = 'Blah';
```

After this you can do `SELECT @id` to get the ID of the updated row.

Comment: don't know much about MySQL, but what is the second `SELECT @id`? Is it another statement after the UPDATE?

Comment: That's how you set a user variable in MySQL = `@id := id` sets the variable `@id` from the `id` column of the selected row.